# itoa function problem

Tags: c++, portability, itoa

I'm working on Eclipse inside Ubuntu environment on my C++ project.

I use the `itoa` function (which works perfectly on Visual Studio) and the compiler complains that `itoa` is undeclared.

I included `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<iostream>` which doesn't help.

Comment: please post your code, it's difficult to help without it

Comment: @CharlesB: this problem is *very* easy to diagnose without code. There's no need to post the code here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

www.cplusplus.com says:

*This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers.*

Therefore, I'd strongly suggest that you don't use it. However, you can achieve this quite straightforwardly using `stringstream` as follows:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << myInt;
string myString = ss.str();
```

Comment: thanks,
i tried it in visual studio and it does not recognize it,
do i have to include somthing ?

Comment: Error 4 error C2079: 'streamstringKey' uses undefined class 'std::basic_stringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' h:\workspace\hw5\hw5\vehicle.cpp 151

Comment: Error 8 error C2228: left of '.str' must have class/struct/union h:\workspace\hw5\hw5\vehicle.cpp 154


Error 6 error C2297: '<<' : illegal, right operand has type 'char *const ' h:\workspace\hw5\hw5\vehicle.cpp 153



const string Vehicle::GetKey() const{
 stringstream streamstringKey;
 streamstringKey << GetTypeNum();
 streamstringKey << m_licenseId; //m_licenseId is char*
 string stringKey = streamstringKey.str();
        return streamstringKey;
}

Answer (score 8):

`itoa()` is not part of any standard so you shouldn't use it. There's better ways, i.e...

C:

```
int main() {
    char n_str[10];
    int n = 25;

    sprintf(n_str, "%d", n);

    return 0;
}
```

C++:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ostringstream n_str;
    int n = 25;

    n_str << n;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: actually i need to append an int to a string.

Comment: so, can i do it not with ostringstream, because my compiler does not recognize it.

Answer (score 5):

Boost way:

`string str = boost::lexical_cast<string>(n);`

Answer (score 2):

itoa depends on compiler, so better use the following methods :-

method 1 :If you are using c++11, just go for std::to_string. It will do the trick.

method 2 :sprintf works for both c & c++.
ex- 
ex - to_string

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int i;
  char buffer [100];
  printf ("Enter a number: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);

  string str = to_string(i);
  strcpy(buffer, str.c_str());

  cout << buffer << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Note - compile using -std=c++0x.

C++ sprintf:

```
int main ()
{
int i;
  char buffer [100];
  printf ("Enter a number: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);
  sprintf(buffer, "%d", i);
  return 0;
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use sprintf

```
char temp[5];
temp[0]="h"
temp[1]="e"
temp[2]="l"
temp[3]="l"
temp[5]='\0'
sprintf(temp+4,%d",9)
cout<<temp;
```

output would be :hell9

Answer (score 0):

Did you include stdlib.h? (Or rather, since you're using C++, cstdlib)

Comment: That won't necessarily help, since `itoa` is non-standard.