# is there a way to parse a INT to string/char* without using a stream?

Tags: c++, parsing

There are sooo many posts about converting from int to string but they all really involve either just printing to the screen, or using ostringstream.

I was using ostringstream, but my company doesnt want me to use any streams because it has horrid runtimes.

I was doing this in a C++ file.

my issue is that i was going to, over the course of execution create millions of streams, write to the buffers, and then copy content into a string, as such:

```
ostringstream OS;
os << "TROLOLOLOLOL";
std::string myStr = os.str();
```

There is redundancy as it is making this buffer then copying it all over.  UGH!

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense, why not just do `std::string myStr( "TROLOLOLOLOL" );`? Or do you want to build a string incrementally?

Comment: Some hints are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799595/itoa-function-problem

Comment: The "horrid runtimes" argument is bullshit.  I've tested and found maybe a 10% difference  on some occasions, if you bother to set a buffer and don't do anything too boneheaded.

Comment: Yea, i dunno why they say that, but i personally have not tested it, as it is not what im paid to do..  My example was pretty much doing that above code like 2.3million times

Comment: @cHao That isn't a completely bullshit statement. [Here's a great example of it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340396/does-the-c-standard-mandate-poor-performance-for-iostreams-or-am-i-just-deali) But it may or may not apply to this particular example the OP is hitting.

Comment: @Mysticial: It's not *completely* bullshit, but the difference isn't anywhere near as big as some idiot's benchmarks would have you believe.  Like i said, about 10% on some occasions.  Others, i've seen iostreams actually be *faster* when someone bothered to try for performance.

Comment: @cHao That is good to know.  Maybe i am just doing it wrong.  I was thinking that creating streams/buffers, writing to them and copying it all out was just very time confusing.  Was hoping there was a way to do it better. *shrug*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11:

```
string s = std::to_string(42);
```

I did a benchmark a couple of weeks ago, and got those results (using clang and libc++ shipped with current Xcode):

```
stringstream took 446ms
to_string took 203ms
c style took 170ms
```

With the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Measure {
  chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> _start;
  string _name;

  Measure(const string& name) : _name(name) {
    _start = chrono::system_clock::now();
  }

  ~Measure() {
    cout << _name << " took " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::system_clock::now() - _start).count() << "ms" << endl;
  }
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  int n = 1000000;
  {
    Measure m("stringstream");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      stringstream ss;
      ss << i;
      string s = ss.str();
    }
  }
  {
    Measure m("to_string");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      string s = to_string(i);
    }
  }
  {
    Measure m("c style");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      char buff[50];
      snprintf(buff, 49, "%d", i);
      string s(buff);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is a solid bench mark, and over the datasets i need to, makes a HUGE difference.  I might end up doing the c style approach

Comment: You could try reusing the buffer, dunno if that helps a lot.

Comment: Using this same benchmark, but moving the stream creation outside the loop and saying `ss.str("");` to clear it each iteration, i get 190ms runtimes as opposed to `to_string`'s 191ms.  `snprintf` is just slightly faster at 169ms.

Comment: @cHao the implementation matters a lot as well. For example, even with stream creation moved outside the loop on Windows stringstream is still much slower than to_string and sprintf.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 you have [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). Although it probably uses the `stringstream` technique under the hoods.

Comment: Actually it probably uses sprintf as it's specified in terms of that function.

Comment: @bames53 Going by the benchmark by lucas clemente it seems that way.

Comment: Mmmm.  Interesting.  Maybe this is faster then the ostringstream class?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the performance chart of `boost::lexical_cast`:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html

It compares lexical_cast to stringstream (with and without construction) and scanf/printf.

> In most cases boost::lexical_cast is faster than scanf, printf, std::stringstream.

Comment: we dont use boost.  Not sure.  For some reason it didnt get passed Legal.  *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Reusing the stringstream buffer.  Note, this is not thread safe.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
bool str_to_type(const char *str, T &value) {
  static std::stringstream strm;
  if ( str ) {
    strm << std::ends;
    strm.clear();
    strm.setf(std::ios::boolalpha);
    strm.seekp(0);
    strm.seekg(0);
    strm << str << std::ends;
    strm >> value;
    return !strm.fail();
  }
  return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  if (!str_to_type("42", i))
    std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```