# C++ easy way to convert int to string with unknown base

Tags: c++, string, int, type-conversion

Here is code in Java:

```
int a = 456;
int b = 5;
String s = Integer.toString(a, b);
System.out.println(s);
```

Now I want the same in C++, but all the conversions i find convert to base 10 only. I ofc dont want to implement this by mysleft, why to write something what already exists

Comment: I had it backwards. Sorry.

Comment: `itoa()` in `<cstdlib>` will allow you to specify the base (between 2 - 36)..

Comment: _don't want to implement this by myself_. I remember this as a common assignment in beginning programming classes, so any real programmer shouldn't consider it a burden.

Comment: Implement it yourself. It's relatively simple, so you should know how to do this. What if you had a job interview? After that, you can use something better, but you SHOULD be able to reinvent a simple wheel, even if you will later buy a better-designed wheel.

Comment: @Nim, itoa isn't standard C++. It doesn't seem to be standard C either.

Comment: how do i possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225130/c-base-conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although `std::strtol` is more flexible, in a controlled case you can use `itoa` as well.

```
int a = 456;
int b = 5;
char buffer[32];
itoa(a, buffer, b);
```

Comment: buffer size should be 33

Comment: Reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799595/itoa-function-problem, it seems itoa can't be used int C++.

Comment: @keineahnung2345 I think it's not available under Linux, only MS-Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want base 8 or 16 you can easily use the string manipulators [`std::oct`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/oct/) and [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex). If you want arbitrary bases, I suggest checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6478745/86515).

Answer (score 1):

Without error handling http://ideone.com/nCj2XG:

```
char *toString(unsigned int value, unsigned int radix)
{
    char digit[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ";
    char stack[32];
    static char out[33];

    int quot, rem;
    int digits = 0;

    do
    {
        quot = value / radix;
        rem = value % radix;

        stack[digits] = digit[rem];
        value = quot;
        digits++;
    }
    while( value );

    int i = 0;
    while(digits--)
    {
        out[i++] = stack[digits];
    }

    out[i] = 0;

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard function [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/), which performs conversion to an arbitrary calculus system. But for example, in my version of the compiler there is no implementation. My solution:

```
#include <string>

// maximum radix - base36
std::string int2string(unsigned int value, unsigned int radix) {
    const char base36[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    std::string result;
    while (value > 0) {
        unsigned int remainder = value % radix;
        value /= radix;
        result.insert(result.begin(), base36[remainder]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Made changes to the answer.